# Abrir link a partir de um checkbox usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso abrir um link na mesma guia a partir de uma checkbox, onde vou passar parâmetros.

Esse é o HTML:

```html
<div class="prog">
    <legend class="">Genero</legend>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="acao"> Ação<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="aventura" > Aventura<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="esportes" > Esportes<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="rpg" > RPG<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="arcade" > Arcade<br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Em cada um vou passar um parâmetro para fazer a busca no banco de dados, porém não sei o comando em JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

O código abaixo submete o formulário quando qualquer `checkbox` for marcado.

[**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/checkbox-checked-submit.php)

```
<div class="prog">
    <legend class="">Genero</legend>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="acao" onclick="this.form.submit();"> Ação<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="aventura" onclick="this.form.submit();"> Aventura<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="esportes" onclick="this.form.submit();"> Esportes<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="rpg" onclick="this.form.submit();"> RPG<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="genero" value="arcade" onclick="this.form.submit();"> Arcade<br>
    </form>
</div>
```

> **OBS:** As caixas de seleção oferecem a opção de marcar mais de um item.
>   Se a intenção é essa o HTML deve ser estruturado da forma a seguir.  [**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/checkbox-checked-submitB.php)

- Adicione ao name do input o [], ao submeter o form ele será enviado como um array..

  ```
  <div class="prog">
  <legend class="">Genero</legend>
  <form action=""  method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="acao"> Ação<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="aventura"> Aventura<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="esportes"> Esportes<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="rpg"> RPG<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="arcade"> Arcade<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
  ```

Exemplo em PHP na página em que acorrerá a ação

```
if(!empty($_POST['genero'])) {
    foreach($_POST['genero'] as $item) {
            //açãos
    }
}
```